# How to create an ICanvas in .Net MAUI?

Tags: maui

I'm so close to having this working... EDITED

```
private async void DrawThisThing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
#if IOS || ANDROID || MACCATALYST
    //===================

    setAsset(); // save file details as preference

    if (MediaPicker.Default.IsCaptureSupported)
    {

        GetCurrentLocation(); // get lat long of current location

        FileResult photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();

        if (photo != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var fName = projID.Text + "-" + assID.Text + "-" + wDetail.Text + ".jpg";

                Stream sourceStream = await photo.OpenReadAsync();

                devOri = DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Orientation.ToString();
                var image = PlatformImage.FromStream(sourceStream);

                if (image != null)
                {
                    IImage newImage = image.Downsize(1600, true);

                    double lat = 0.0;
                    double lng = 0.0;
                    
                    var skiaBitmap = new SkiaBitmapExportContext((int)newImage.Width, (int)newImage.Height,72);
                    
                    
                    if (latlong != null)
                    {
                        lat = Math.Round(latlong.Latitude, 6);
                        lng = Math.Round(latlong.Longitude, 6);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                    ICanvas canvas = skiaBitmap.Canvas;

                    canvas.FontColor = Colors.White;
                    canvas.FontSize = 72;
                    canvas.Font = Font.Default;
                    canvas.DrawImage(newImage, 0,0,newImage.Width,newImage.Height);
                    canvas.DrawString(lat.ToString() + " : " + lng.ToString(), 0, 0, 1600, 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left, VerticalAlignment.Top);
                    canvas.SaveState();

                    using (MemoryStream _result = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        skiaBitmap.WriteToStream(_result);

                        _result.Position = 0;

                        savetoGallery(_result, fName);

                        fileSaveLoc.Text = fName;
                        
                        if (latlong != null)
                        {
                            latlngRes.Text = lat.ToString() + " : " + lng.ToString();
                            latlong = null;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            latlngRes.Text = "Unable to Retreive Location";
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "Ok");
            }
        }
    }

#endif
}
```

EDIT: Ok, I've had success using Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Skia. Code above edited to new working code. The only issue now is the DrawImage function isn't actually drawing the image on the canvas.

Anyone know why? I've tried loading a local image to the canvas and that doesn't work either so it definitely seems to be something not working with the DrawImage function?

Comment: You cannot instantiate interfaces. By convention, anything that starts with a capital "I" usually indicates that it's an interface and not an implementation, e.g. `ICanvas`, `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and so on. You also shouldn't try to instantiate a canvas inside an event handler. Instead, you should add a [GraphicsView](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/graphicsview) to your XAML and then [draw on the canvas it provides](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/graphics/draw), e.g. by implementing your own drawable.

Comment: I've already created a XAML view as a learning exercise. The issue is now I want to extend that learning to draw on a photo from the camera and save it to a memorystream.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with a GraphicsView. You may want to check out SkiaSharp instead. A quick search also yielded the following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/901382/save-an-image-using-maui-net-graphics

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Interfaces are nothing but a sort of contracts. You cannot make ICanvas objects.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface

Classes are the types that can be used to create objects.
(Not all of them thou)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/classes

I think you should start from here, before trying to do something complex.

Comment: Hmm, ok so I have fallen well outside of my knowledge level here it seems. Thanks for the links, I'll have to keep trying to find a solution.

Comment: @KSD050 This code you have is from drawing view example in the MSFT site. I say check out SkiaSharp. Its not like Maui graphics are something different.